# How can I setup Git/Drush dl/make caching of Drupal projects?

Tags: drush, version-control

I'd like to setup the ability to have Drupal projects cached locally when I do a Git clone or Drush dl/make, so that if I happen to be offline or just to save bandwidth, when I Git clone/Drush dl/make a project that has previously been downloaded it will pull from the cache instead of from D.o., possibly after pinging D.o to see if there is a newer version (if online).

I'm sure I saw something about this once before, but haven't been able to track down the specifics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a blog post about locally cached git repositories here: http://randyfay.com/node/93

Answer (score 4):

Drush 5 now has a `--cache` flag which builds up a cache automatically, just as described at http://randyfay.com/node/93.

We have started integrating Drush Make into Drush core and at that time, make will get Drush core's caching features (like what dl and updatecode have).

Answer (score 0):

As the answer was only relevant to the Git, I did a little searching and came across an Issue in D.o. for Drush make that lead to a blog post on how to use Squid to cache Drush dl commands, the blog post is a tad broken due to the Geshi Filter module not running or working correctly, but the information seems like it will be valid. Still trying to wrap my head around it.

- D.o issue: http://drupal.org/node/698104
- Blog post/Tutorial: http://reluctanthacker.rollett.org/node/114